# How to change snaplex dynamically based upon usage?

Tags: snaplogic

While executing child pipeline I want to fetch all the snaplex available and assign them based on the usage to the child pipeline. So far I am able to randomize the snaplex while spawning the clild pipeline.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly the requirement is but if performance is what you are concerned with then I would suggest running child pipelines on the same plex as the parent.

As per SnapLogic documentation -

> When running a parent and child Pipeline on the same node, data is not transferred over a network, which improves the performance of the Pipeline execution.

This is because -

> When using the Pipeline Execute Snap, if you specify a different Snaplex to run a child Pipeline, then the input documents and Pipeline parameters are passed (through the control plane using encrypted transport) to a node in the designated Snaplex.

Please refer to - [SnapLogic Docs - Managing Snaplexes](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1437953/Managing+Snaplexes)